# Using JWT with a secret key to handle Single Sign On

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, jwt

I have a running members only website that works as it should with login etc.
I now need to support Single Sign On where I will recieve the username of the profile in a JWT token, and then log the user in.
The external system that will send this request, does NOT know any other information than the Username - so the password is not shared in the token, nor is it possible.

JWT has been chosen as the method of choice to enable this. We are going to use a secret key to exchange the information, the secret key is ofcourse only know by the sender and reciever.

What I am looking for is a simple example of how this could look code-wise, both in the sender end and in the recieving end.
The reciever end will be a WebAPI endpoint that will handle the login and then redirect to the frontpage of the members-only website if the login is successfull.

It is developed in C#.

Comment: _"What I am looking for is a simple example of how this could look code-wise"_ - such a thing does not exist: there's simply far too many moving parts. Also, please clarify **exactly** what you mean by "Single-Sign-On" because the fact you're using JWT doesn't mean you're running your own OIDC IdP, for example.

Comment: Are yours webs  csr or a ssr with c#? How many webs and microservices are in your infrastructure? Are you looking for an enterprise strategy or is just a poc?

Comment: @JRichardsz it's a SSR with C# in the recieving end. Just a simple POC to help with my own insights into the best solution and way to handle the task.

I have the login itself in place - so i have code that can take a username only, and then log the user in. The step I am missing, is the encrypt and decrypt of the JWT data using the secret key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Elementary tips

- Usually and commonly, the user/password are exchanged for a new JWT
- JWT should not store anything sensible like a password. Some companies like Microsoft store not a sensible values but a lot of information https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/6512f9b2b4c38620bf00e24c71b6cf2d
- For an enterprises, the encrypt and decrypt process should not be executed at the microservice layer. It should be performed by another server like: Auth0, okta, Keycloack, etc.
- Your microservice only receives the token and send it to the security platform,. The best way to do this is with a middleware on any language. This is for [c#](https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/98973450d2166650f709ce2d47dcaef5#file-c-middlware-md)

  [image]
- The security platform returns a response with data in a syntax that client (c# in your case) understand if token is legit, valid, not expired, user exist, user is allowed to perform the operation, etc. I used this in some implementation in which I said: "User is allowed to perform this operation and this is its username"

  **endpoint:** `acme-security.com/v1/oauth2/token/validate`

  **request:** `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi...`

  **response:**

  ```
  {
  "isAllowed": true,
  "subject": "jane@blindspot.com"
  }
  ```
- Also you can do this with an api gateway

  [image]
- On a more real scenario, we need more than a simple jwt validation. We need to ensure that user admin/guest are allowed to execute specific endpoints. We don't want that a employee invoke directly the payment endpoint set its own salary :/
- Follow the oauth2 spec if you will implement your own security platform
- Jwt should be sent as Authorization Header
- **IMPORTANT:** If you will implement your own jwt generation and validation, use ENV variables to hide it the secret and protect it as much as you can for your production environment

### JWT handling with c# netcore 5

If the previous steps are understood, you only need one of these approaches:

- Use some IAM or security platforms like auth0, okta, keycloack, etc
- A simple c# web/microservice/api (that also functions as security platform) to receive token and return if user is allowed
- A class to to the validation inside of the target microservice

**JWT Generation**

```
public string GenerateToken(User user)
{
    // generate token that is valid for 7 days
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SUPER_SECRET_KEY);
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim("id", user.Id.ToString()) }),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };
    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
}
```

**JWT Decode or validation**

```
public int? ValidateToken(string token)
{
    if (token == null) 
        return null;

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SUPER_SECRET_KEY);
    try
    {
        tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            // set clockskew to zero so tokens expire exactly at token expiration time (instead of 5 minutes later)
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        }, out SecurityToken validatedToken);

        var jwtToken = (JwtSecurityToken)validatedToken;
        var userId = int.Parse(jwtToken.Claims.First(x => x.Type == "id").Value);

        // return user id from JWT token if validation successful
        return userId;
    }
    catch
    {
        // return null if validation fails
        return null;
    }
}
```

Source: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/06/02/net-5-create-and-validate-jwt-tokens-use-custom-jwt-middleware

This code throws errors when token is expired or some buddy tries to send a jwt without your **SUPER_SECRET_KEY**

You could use these snippets directly in your token generation and inside of your endpoints

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<List<Dictionary<string, object>>> findAllEmployees()
{
    //get jwt from http received headers
    validationResponse = ValidateToken(jwt)
    //if you have a security platform, callhere instead
    //ValidateToken(jwt)
    //if validationResponse.isAllowed ....
    var list = this.employeeService.findAllEmployees();
    return Ok(list);
}
```

or with a middleware like a pro, to keep clean your final controllers

### Lectures

- https://jrichardsz-java.medium.com/how-to-generate-and-validate-jwt-token-b5b265d5e0b